# Not able to print the variable in chrome dev tools javascript console

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, debugging, developer-tools

Below image is pointing the value of username (updatedBy) i.e 52038862.
I want to print this value by calling the variable which stores this value. The value displayed in the table.

[image]

How to fetch the variable name and print this in javascript console. I need to display this value in some other pages. I am newly debugging the application. I am stuck at this point. Below is my jsp code.

```
<label>Approval History</label>        
            </div>
            <div class="tile-body">
                <div class="tableWrapAtX">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Date/Time</th>
                                <th>User</th>
                                <th>Email Address</th>
                                <th>Old Status</th>
                                <th>New Status</th>
                                <th>Comment</th>                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                                         
                            <!-- ko foreach: approvalAuditTrail -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: updated"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: updatedBy"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: updatedByEmail"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: oldStatus"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: approvalStatus"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: comments"></span></td>
                                </tr>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is that value stored in a variable or just in the html

Comment: I have updated the question's description. Added the jsp code from approval.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you assign an ID to the field and reference it that way?

```
<td><span id="updateby" data-bind="text: updatedBy"></span></td>
```

Create a variable `$foo` to reference this data in the DOM.

```
$foo = document.querySelector('span#updateby');
```

Retrieve properties of the $foo variable, specifically the actual int values

```
$foo.textContent;
```

There are different ways to reference as well and this simple example is based on my understanding of the question.

[image: Google Chrome console output]